# Run bash command from python and capture file object

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook

in jupyter notebook I can run the following command and get a list of file objects that I can then open:

```
PATH = someuser/data
files = get_ipython().getoutput('ls {PATH}') #%ls {PATH} in notebook
#then I can run
text = get_ipython().getoutput('less {PATH}{files[0]}')
print(text)
```

I have tried the following:

```
path = f"{PATH}"
files = subprocess.call(['ls', path])

files = subprocess.run(['ls', path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')

files = os.system(path)
```

But I can only get a string object not file objects that I can then open and get data from.

Comment: Filenames _are_ strings. That's what you pass to the `open` function to get a file object. Which you can then get data from.

Comment: However, you don't need to call out to `ls` to get a list of files; use `os.listdir` for that.

Comment: Also, why are you using `os.system` in the last line? You obviously know about `subprocess`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filenames *are* strings. That's what you pass to `open` to get a file object, which you can then get data from. For example, let's say you have a script called `spam.py`:

```
filename = 'spam.py'
with open(filename) as fileobj:
    data = fileobj.read()
print(data)
```

When you run it, it prints itself out.

Now, the output you got back from calling `subprocess.run` on `ls` and reading its `stdout` is not a string for each file, but one big string.

The simple answer here is to just not call out to `ls`. Python can already get a list of filenames for you:

```
filenames = os.listdir(path)
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename) as fileobj:
        # do stuff with fileobj
```

But if you really must, you can use, e.g., the `splitlines` method to turn the output you have into a list of lines, which will be much the same as what `listdir` returns, just retrieved in a more convoluted way.